# Using sed to replace a whitespace followed by the word "ora.(anything)" to a new line and the word "ora.(anything)"

Tags: regex, linux, sed

As the title says, i'm trying to use sed to replace, say,

```
ora.LISTENER_SCAN1.lsnr 1 ONLINE ONLINE myserver1 ora.LISTENER_SCAN2.lsnr 1 ONLINE ONLINE myserver2
```

into:

```
ora.LISTENER_SCAN1.lsnr 1 ONLINE ONLINE myserver1
ora.LISTENER_SCAN2.lsnr 1 ONLINE ONLINE myserver2
```

I've tried using: sed 's/ ora*/\n/g' but to no avail. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In any case, it is best to include the period after `ora` in the search pattern; otherwise you will also break at `[space]oracle` and even at `[space]orange`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to replace `[space]ora.` with `[newline]ora.`, do EXACTLY THAT in SED:

```
's/ ora\./\nora\./g'
```

Comment: A few notes: this will introduce a blank line; not every sed can insert a newline by using `\n` in the replacement string.

Comment: I've tried this and the output remains with no new lines

Comment: @ShvartZ - It works on my machine. What version of Linux are you using? In any case, **this** (what Benjamin said) may be your issue; it is not quite the same as what you asked initially.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - you said **a few** notes. I only see one. Did you mean to say more?

Comment: @mathguy RHEL 5.11 is the server's OS version (yup I know)

Comment: For the record, `sed --version` on my machine reports `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`. I am on Oracle Linux 7.5; in the Oracle world, this is a successor to RHEL. It should be about the same as RHEL 7.5.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did have two at first, then realized that the other one was not valid ;)

Comment: Actually, this still are two (introduces blank line, might not work with `\n`). The third one was about shortening by using `&`, but that would have kept the blank.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - I missed the "blank" line as part of your original comment. No, on my machine the solution I provided does not introduce a blank line - it only splits the input line into two lines. There are no "blank" lines in the output.

Comment: Oh, right, because the `ora` has no leading blank! Time for a coffee...